# Maximum 2x2 squares in given rectangle

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix of size nxm which consists of 0s and 1s..so i have to place 2x2 squares in matrix where there is 0. You cant place square where 1 is present.
The question is maximum 2x2 squares that can be placed in given 3x5 matrix eg
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1..
So in above example we can place max of two 2x2 in the matrix.
How to solve it?

Comment: Can you give the link to the original problem? Reading with the original wording would help.

Answer (score 1):

If the $ 3 \times 5 $ matrix is a fixed one, then one can relatively easily eye-ball the solution, so assume you always have different matrix and what you really wanted is an algorithm that can solve this for any given $ 3 \times 5 $ matrix in a reasonable amount of time.

Finding all the candidate position when you can place a matrix is straightforward, you just try all $ 2 \times 4 $ positions as the upper left corner and see if it is a valid solution.

If two candidate position overlaps, then they conflicts each other. If one model the candidate positions as nodes and conflict as edges, then you are really trying to find the maximum independent set of this graph.

Finding maximum independent set is NP hard, it is unlikely you will have a fast algorithm for this, but fortunately you can have at most 8 rectangles, even if you brute force all $ 2^8 $ possibility it isn't bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 2. First, you need to find the possibilities of 2x2 matrices arrangement in your nxm matrix. Here, for 3x5 : 
[00100]
[00100]
[00111]

You can see that the possible fixes of 2x2 matrix could be:

1=>
[ab100]
[cd100]
[00111]

2=>
[00100]
[ab100]
[cd111]

3=>
[001ab]
[001cd]
[00111]
where 
[ab]
[cd] => your 2x2 matrix.

Now try to look fill each possibility. And the count the number of the possibilities you were able to fill out. That will be your answer.

Note: Assumed that your 2x2 matrix doesn't contain any zeroes.